# How to map # to ~ in gnome-terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal

The `~` key of my laptop is broken, now I am seeking a method to map the # to it? How could I do it?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to change. The only sensible thing I can think of is to bind a different key to the `~` character. This depends on your terminal emulator (xterm, gnome-terminal, konsole, …): what terminal emulator do you use? Maybe you should change the system configuration instead; that depends somewhat on your desktop environment (Gnome, KDE, …).

Answer (score 1):

Keycode of `3`/`#` key is 12:

```
]$ xmodmap -pk | grep "(3)"
    12         0x0033 (3)      0x0023 (numbersign)     0x0033 (3)      0x0023 (numbersign)
```

(`xmodmap -pk` displays current mapping)

You need to change mapping of this key when pressed with shift so it produces `~` instead of `#`. You do this like this:

```
echo "keycode 12 = 3 asciitilde" >> ~/.Xmodmap
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

In order to reset mapping back to original you remove above line from `~/.Xmodmap` and do:

```
]$ xmodmap -e "keycode 12 = 3 numbersign"
```